# Integrating xib file to stroyboard under UI scrollView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview

As in the screenshot 1, I am trying to design view that is longer then screen size of iPhone.
and in second screenshot I changed the size to freeform which is giving me liberty to create longer view than iPhone's length.
My question is is it a standard way to solve this problem. where as my understanding was that we are not suppose to use xib files anymore after storyboard because every thing was moved to storyboard.
So to solve this this problem Do I have to use view(xib) and make it as subview of UIscroll view.
is that a standard way to solve these kind of problems or do we have something with storyboard equivalent which is more efficient ?

PS: I have been researching this problem from past few days. All related questions over here and web, are adding UIView programmatically to ViewController but not a single example I found where one is designing the UIView in Xcode thru xib file and adding it to UIScroll View. Which is common real world problem. all the app where views are longer or wider than screen size are not done programmatically all together. At least I think they are being designed and them added to the Viewcontroller. Please correct me If I am wrong.

[image: without Freeform]
[image: Freeform]

Comment: Please be clear. What do u want exactly? SHow us ur tries or some visualization.

Comment: Looking at the long list of labels that you've added, the answer that would occur to 99% of iPhone devs is imho UITableView

Comment: @jef it took labels as example. Which just represent the UI element on the screen. it could many buttons, labels. What I am trying to accomplish to have having scrolling view and designing that that. I am not creating view at run time or programatically. All I find is how to do it programatically. I wanna design it in storyboard (which seems not possible) and I have to use xib file.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, as it's always been on iPhone, modal views which come and go as needed. You can temporarily add child view controllers, alert views, 3rd party iphone compatible popover knockoffs....

Answer (score 0):

Of course `UIView` still exists - so where is the problem? What you probably mean is that you cannot set an `UIView` in a `storyboard`, storyboards only contain view controllers. But you can **still make a xib file containing an UIView of any size you like**, and add that one to your scroll view.